# WordPress AJAX , return data issue

Tags: json, ajax, wordpress, response

After many tries and search the web, I asked some help because I am getting crazy for real.

I'm doing the most simple AJAX call in one of my WordPress template files.

The issue is that the returned data (response.responseText) is the full html content of my homepage (from !doctype to /html), so strange.

I'm really scared, because I've no idea what's wrong and can't find answers for same issue on web.

Here is the JS :

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    $('#myselector').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax( {
            url: myvar.url,
            type: 'post',
            // if uncommented, console.log shows parseerror
            //dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                action: myvar.action,
                nonce: myvar.nonce,
                uid: myvar.uid
            },
        })
        .done( function( response, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
            console.log(response)
            console.log(textStatus)
            console.log(jqXHR)
        })
        .fail( function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
            console.log(textStatus)
        })
        .then( function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
            console.log(textStatus)
        })
    });

})();
```

This JavaScript is loaded with wp_enqueue_scripts :

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'fileid', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/myJSfile.js' ), array( 'jquery' ), null, true );

    wp_localize_script( 'fileid', 'myvar', array(
        'url'    => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'action' => 'my_action',
        'nonce'  => wp_create_nonce( 'my_nonce' ),
    ) );

} );
```

And the action function in functions.php :

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action_action', 'my_action_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action_action', 'my_action_action' );

function my_action() {

    if ( ! check_ajax_referer( 'my_nonce', 'nonce' ) )
        wp_send_json_error();

    $data = array(
        'success' => 1,
        'data' => 'What s wrong?',
    );

    wp_send_json_success( $data );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action' );
```

function my_action() {

```
if ( ! check_ajax_referer( 'my_nonce', 'nonce' ) )
    wp_send_json_error();

$data = array(
    'success' => 1,
    'data' => 'What s wrong?',
);

wp_send_json_success( $data );

exit;
}
```

Please refer this [click here](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) 
Hope it works.

Comment: I get the same result unfortunately.

Comment: Have you get admin url in javascript?

Comment: Still the same result. And the admin url is in the script yes.

Comment: change your permalink and add "exit" at end of function

Comment: I've tried with exit; and also tries with an echo json_encode(...); exit; Wich permalink you're talking about?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168640/discussion-between-fredmat-and-vrajesh).